# Read in two files from same directory

Tags: python, file-io, directory, multiple-file-upload

I am writing a program in Python that is trying to read in two different files from the same directory. My code looks like this:

```
for i in spectra_files:                                           
    with open(i, 'r') as f:
        numbers = []  #list to store all mass spectrum data directly from file before being processed
        for line in f:
            if line[0].isdigit():  #skips header in file
                numbers.append(line)

        str_data = ''.join(numbers)
        #creates list for the mass and list for the intensity. to be used for plotting
        spectrum_mass = [int(x.split(',')[0].strip()) for x in str_data.split()]
        spectrum_intensity = [int(x.split(',')[1].strip()) for x in str_data.split()]
        spectrum_mass.append('||')
        spectrum_intensity.append('||')
        spectra_files = spectra_files[spectra_files.index(i)+1:]
```

Currently I have it looping through a list of the names of the files, and then adding their data to the lists spectrum_mass and spectrum_intensity. However this is not working and it is only adding the data from the last file in the list. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you're reassigning things every time through the loop.

Comment: I tried appending to the two lists but that didn't work either. It was just appending the same data, the one from the last file. @TigerhawkT3

Comment: define ` spectrum_mass` and `spectrum_intensity` out of the loop as empty list `[]` and do not modify `spectra_files` in the loop. The for loop takes care of everything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes:

- extend lists you construct OUTSIDE of your loop.
- you need to NOT change the list you iterate on while iterating it. I'm referring to the `spectra_files` list which you change at the end of your loop (`spectra_files = spectra_files[spectra_files.index(i)+1:]`)

.

```
spectrum_mass = []
spectrum_intensity = []
for i in spectra_files:                                           
    with open(i, 'r') as f:
        numbers = []  #list to store all mass spectrum data directly from file before being processed
        for line in f:
            if line[0].isdigit():  #skips header in file
                numbers.append(line)

        str_data = ''.join(numbers)
        #creates list for the mass and list for the intensity. to be used for plotting
        spectrum_mass.extend(int(x.split(',')[0].strip()) for x in str_data.split())
        spectrum_intensity.extend(int(x.split(',')[1].strip()) for x in str_data.split())
        spectrum_mass.append('||')
        spectrum_intensity.append('||')
```

Comment: Thank you! I am relatively new to Python and didn't know about extend.

Comment: So Extend isn't terminology to pay attention too. What he's saying is you're recycling the same variable. *Place your lists to be used outside of the for loop so they aren't created each time. Keep one and append.

Answer (score 0):

Create lists outside the loop. For each iteration the list is getting over written. And one more suggestion;
When you ask question; please skip irrelevant code of what are you doing with the lines in the file do a minimal dummy code. It makes it much more easier to follow and answer.

In your code still you are not "Reading" in 2 files simultaneously. You are reading in a loop one file at a time and "Writing" in 2 lists simultaneously.

I hope it helps